# Validation Rule on user when profile change

Tags: apex, validation, validation-rule

Requirement:When User Profile is getting changed to some other profiles then error needs to come.
Suppose I am changing profile to (P1,P2,P3)then error needs to come..
If(Or(profile==p1,profile=p2)) then error.
How can i achieve this using validation rule.
Please help.

Comment: Need Validation on user object

Comment: what do u want exactly ? throw error when changed user profile is it? lets discussed on chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31089/disscution

Answer (score 0):

Should be easy to do

```
ISCHANGED( ProfileId ) && OR ( ProfileId = 'id1',ProfileId ='id2',ProfileId ='id3' )
```

Replace id1, id2 and id3 with the ids of the profiles you want.

**OR**

```
ISCHANGED( ProfileId ) && OR ( Profile.Name = 'Profile_Name_1',Profile.Name = 'Profile_Name_2')
```

Replace the names with the profiles that you want.

Comment: Thanks,But I have almost 100 profiles so can i use custom label or do i need to write in validation rule itself.I want to proceed with name instead of Profile Id

Comment: Updated the answer.